# Question on the covariance and independence of a random vector.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am given a random vector $(X,Y)$ with joint density given by

$$ f(x,y) =  \begin{cases} 
      2 \lambda xe^{-\lambda y} &   0\leq x < 1 , y> 0 \\[5pt]
0  & \mbox{otherwise}
       \end{cases}
$$

with $\lambda > 0$. I am tasked with finding the covariance of $(X,Y)$ and saying if $X$ is independent from $Y$ and if $X$ is independent from $XY$.

**My attempt at a solution:**

Given that I find that the density of $Y$ is of exponential form and the one of $X$ is of uniform form I calculate the covariance as:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{+ \infty} (x - 1/2) (y - 1/ {\lambda}) 2 \lambda x e^{- \lambda y} = -\frac{2}{\lambda^2 3} + \frac{2}{\lambda 3}.$$

then because the product of the densities is not equal to the joint density I deduce that $X$ is not independent from $Y$. Now I am left with the last point for which I proceed as follows:

I call $XY = Z$

$$P(XY = z ) = \int_0^{+\infty} P(XY = z | Y = y) P(Y = y)dy  = e^{- z \lambda /x} - 1 $$

and 
$$P(Z = z, X = x) = P(Z = z |X = x) P(X = x) = \lambda e^{-z \lambda/x } $$

So even in this case they are not independent?

I am unsure of my solutions (especially the last) if it is wrong could someone tell me why and how to proceed otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The marginal densities are $f_X(x)=2x$ and $f_Y(y)=\lambda e^{-\lambda y}$, notice $f_X(x)f_Y(y)=f(x,y)$ therefore they are independent and $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=0 \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$. 

Calculate $$\begin{align} \mathrm{Cov}(XY,X) & =\mathbb{E}[X^2Y]-\mathbb{E}[XY]\mathbb{E}[X]\\ &=(\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2)\mathbb{E}[Y] \\ & =\mathrm{Var}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]\\ & \ne 0\end{align}$$